# push array into an array object without property declared

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

```
parent = {[
"item":""
]}

child = [1,2,3]
```

to push my child into parent I can do

```
$.each(function(){
this.item = child;
}
```

but how to push the child into the item property if I don't have the item property declare the parent? It's quite redundant to have the item equal to empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same thing without setting item at all. If the property is not defined. It will be automatically created.

```
parent = {[
]}

child = [1,2,3]
```

then

```
$.each(function(){
this.item = child;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
parent = {[
"item":"";
]}
```

it is not a valid syntax. Try with:

```
var parent = {
  "item": [];
};

var child = [1,2,3];

parent.item = child;
```

or

```
parent.item = parent.item.concat(child);
```

Comment: hsz is right. you know you will have an array, so initialize with empty array first